# Duplicated x co-ordinates for scipy interpolation

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

In the scipy.interpolate library, which functions are able to interpolate a set of data points X,Y, where X and Y are arrays, despite the presence of duplicated points in the X array?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use parametric interpolation - see [Jaime's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344099/numpy-scipy-smooth-spline-representation-of-an-arbitrary-contour-flength)