# Extend line to smoothly connect with another line

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two curves that look like this:

[image: fig1]

I'm looking for a way to smoothly *connect* the blue curve with the red one by extending the former (blue line) **upwards and to the right**, while leaving the latter (red line) untouched. The direction is important, I mention this because it looks as if it would be easier to continue the blue line to the left. I can't do this (it wouldn't make sense in my larger code) so it has to be upwards and to the right.

Here's what I've managed to do so far (the section where the two lines get close is zoomed in):

[image: fig2]

Basically I'm interpolating a new curve using a sample of points from both curves (the black dots) The `MWE` code to obtain this plot is below.

What I need to do now is find a way to trim the green line from the point where it meets the red line to the point where it meets the blue line and *extend* the blue line replacing the little last segment that is now no longer necessary.

This is how the blue line should look after the changes above are applied (made by hand):

[image: fig3]

where the trimmed section of the green line is now a part of the blue line. Notice that I have:

1. discarded the extra points of the green line that extend beyond the intersection with the red line
2. discarded the extra points of the green line that extend beyond the intersection with the blue line.
3. attached the remaining section of the green line to the blue line after discarding the portion of the blue line that extended to the left beyond the intersection of the green and blue lines.

Since I already have the interpolating curve (the green line), all I need is a way to:

1. Trim it up to the points where it intersects the other two curves as explained above.
2. Replace the last portion of the blue line with this trimmed portion of the new interpolated line.

In this particular example I've used fixed lists to plot and perform the calculations, but I have several pairs of lines for which I need to perform a similar operation, so the solution would have to be general enough to contemplate cases with similarly shaped but different curves. How could I do this?

I'm open to solutions making use of `numpy`, `scipy` or whatever is necessary.

Here's the `MWE`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Red line data.
x1 = [0.01, 0.04, 0.08, 0.11, 0.15, 0.18, 0.22, 0.25, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.38, 0.41, 0.44, 0.46, 0.49, 0.51, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58]
y1 = [2.04, 2.14, 2.24, 2.34, 2.44, 2.54, 2.64, 2.74, 2.84, 2.94, 3.04, 3.14, 3.24, 3.34, 3.44, 3.54, 3.64, 3.74, 3.84, 3.94]

# Blue line data.
x2 = [0.4634, 0.4497, 0.4375, 0.4268, 0.4175, 0.4095, 0.4027, 0.3971, 0.3925, 0.389, 0.3865, 0.3848, 0.384, 0.3839, 0.3845, 0.3857, 0.3874, 0.3896, 0.3922, 0.3951, 0.3982, 0.4016, 0.405, 0.4085, 0.412, 0.4154, 0.4186, 0.4215, 0.4242, 0.4265, 0.4283, 0.4297, 0.4304, 0.4305, 0.4298, 0.4284, 0.4261, 0.4228, 0.4185, 0.4132, 0.4067, 0.399, 0.39, 0.3796, 0.3679, 0.3546, 0.3397, 0.3232, 0.305, 0.285]
y2 = [1.0252, 1.0593, 1.0934, 1.1275, 1.1616, 1.1957, 1.2298, 1.2639, 1.298, 1.3321, 1.3662, 1.4003, 1.4344, 1.4685, 1.5026, 1.5367, 1.5708, 1.6049, 1.639, 1.6731, 1.7072, 1.7413, 1.7754, 1.8095, 1.8436, 1.8776, 1.9117, 1.9458, 1.9799, 2.014, 2.0481, 2.0822, 2.1163, 2.1504, 2.1845, 2.2186, 2.2527, 2.2868, 2.3209, 2.355, 2.3891, 2.4232, 2.4573, 2.4914, 2.5255, 2.5596, 2.5937, 2.6278, 2.6619, 2.696]

x3, y3 = [], []

# Store a small section of the blue line in these new lists: only those points
# closer than 0.2 to the last point in this line.
for indx,y2_i in enumerate(y2):
    if (y2[-1]-y2_i)<=0.2:
        y3.append(y2_i)
        x3.append(x2[indx])

# The same as above but for the red line: store only those points between
# 0. and 0.4 in the y axis and with a larger x value than the last point in the
# blue line.
for indx,y1_i in enumerate(y1):
    if 0. <(y1_i-y2[-1])<=0.4 and x1[indx] > x2[-1]:
        y3.append(y1_i)
        x3.append(x1[indx])

# Find interpolating curve that joins both segments stored in x3,y3.
poli_order = 3 # Order of the polynome.
poli = np.polyfit(y3, x3, poli_order)
y_pol = np.linspace(min(y3), max(y3), 50)
p = np.poly1d(poli)
x_pol = [p(i) for i in y_pol]

plt.plot(x1,y1, 'r')
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'b')
plt.plot(x_pol,y_pol, 'g')
plt.scatter(x3,y3,c='k')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Use only two points on one line and two points on the other and do a spline interpolation or a Bezier one.

Comment: Care to put your proposal in the form of an answer? :)

Comment: I even expanded it a little but I'd like not to spend time writing code for it (busy day, coming here only when code is compiling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned, try using a spline. Your smooth curve isn't so smooth in the derivative, going from the continuous line to the straight one looks like a discontinuity in f'(x). Because of that I tightened the bounds down to 0.2 from 0.4 which grabs only a single point for the fits of the red line. Without that the spline will over-interpolate around the extra red points.

A quick example using your defs. from above:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
sx = np.array(x2+x3)
sy = np.array(y2+y3)
t  = np.arange(sx.size,dtype=float)
t /= t[-1]
N  = np.linspace(0,1,2000)
SX = spline(t,sx,N,order=4)
SY = spline(t,sy,N,order=4)

plt.plot(x1,y1, 'r')
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'b')
plt.scatter(x3,y3,c='k')

plt.plot(SX, SY,'g',alpha=.7,lw=3)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

This question is a handy reference:

[Smooth spline representation of an arbitrary contour, f(length) --> x,y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344099/numpy-scipy-smooth-spline-representation-of-an-arbitrary-contour-flength)

Comment: I tried applying this code while tightening the bound to 0.2 as you said and I got this: http://postimg.org/image/71uwstq7l/ Would you mind posting the entire code to see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Scratch the above comment. I just realized you removed the `for` block where I add points from the blue curve to `x3,y3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 2 points on one line and two points on the other (as long as they are on the right side of the intersection) and use do a [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) between them 4.

Or, a nicer result (sometimes) is to use [Bezier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) curves (and now you can have have more than 4 points at the cost of increased complexity) or even [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) ones. Unfortunately, it has been sometime since I played with them and I'd like not to write some code for that.

when picking the curve, take a good look at their properties. For example, Bezier guarantees that the curve will never leave the convex poligon determined by the points so it is clearly a good candidate for what you need.