# AttributeError: module 'scipy.interpolate' has no attribute 'spline'

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline, cubic-spline

I'm using Python 3.6 and trying to run the following code which is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344099/smooth-spline-representation-of-an-arbitrary-contour-flength-x-y/18091373#18091373):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

x = np.array([ 2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  3.])
y = np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  1.])
plt.plot(x,y, label='poly')

t = np.arange(x.shape[0], dtype=float)
t /= t[-1]
nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt)
y1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='range_spline')

t = np.zeros(x.shape)
t[1:] = np.sqrt((x[1:] - x[:-1])**2 + (y[1:] - y[:-1])**2)
t = np.cumsum(t)
t /= t[-1]
x2 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt)
y2 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='dist_spline')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

But it generates an error, `AttributeError: module 'scipy.interpolate' has no attribute 'spline'`.

Then I modify to the following by import `make_interp_spline` from `scipy.interpolate`:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x = np.array([ 2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  3.])
y = np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  1.])
plt.plot(x,y, label='poly')

t = np.arange(x.shape[0], dtype=float)
t /= t[-1]
nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
x1 = make_interp_spline(t, x, nt)
y1 = make_interp_spline(t, y, nt)
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='range_spline')

t = np.zeros(x.shape)
t[1:] = np.sqrt((x[1:] - x[:-1])**2 + (y[1:] - y[:-1])**2)
t = np.cumsum(t)
t /= t[-1]
x2 = make_interp_spline(t, x, nt)
y2 = make_interp_spline(t, y, nt)
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='dist_spline')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I get an new error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2b54020d8fb1> in <module>
     12 t /= t[-1]
     13 nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
---> 14 x1 = make_interp_spline(t, x, nt)
     15 y1 = make_interp_spline(t, y, nt)
     16 plt.plot(x1, y1, label='range_spline')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py in make_interp_spline(x, y, k, t, bc_type, axis, check_finite)
    751 
    752     # special-case k=0 right away
--> 753     if k == 0:
    754         if any(_ is not None for _ in (t, deriv_l, deriv_r)):
    755             raise ValueError("Too much info for k=0: t and bc_type can only "

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Just wonder how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Please show where exactly does the last ValueError comes from.

Comment: I add the full `ValueError`, please check.

Comment: Ok, then it's clear, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument of make_interp_spline is the spline order (i.e. 3 for cubic splines) and you are calling it with the array `nt`.

If you want to specify your own knots, use the `t=...` kwarg.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand. Can you run the code and display the results? Thanks.